# UIWebview always loading with horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Im crating a simple wrapper, however no matter what device I test a website with loading it into a webview its always a bit to wide and has horizontal scrolling. I can turn that off by changing the content size but then i just cut off part of the view on the right hand side.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView?

let endpointURL : String = "http://www.google.com/"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webView?.delegate = self
    var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: endpointURL)!
    var request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView?.loadRequest(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    //webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: After Looking at the picture I posted blown up i realized IB was adding a padding to the left hand side. referancing "viewport" included the padding in width ... problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `webView.scalesPageToFit = true`
This should size the web page to fit the size of the UIWebView.

I suspect your problem might be related to the frame of the WebView.Try resizing your webview to your screen bounds.

```
webView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```